# Android Studio unknown keycode - keymaps don't work with letters

Tags: android, linux, android-studio, fedora-21

That's what I have now: fresh installed Fedora 21, GNOME3 and Android Studio. Two KB languages: ru and en. Whatever is done further is done with "en" input language chosen. System language is Russian.
What I do: try any Ctrl or Ctrl-Alt or Ctrl-Shift shortcuts with any letter. No result at all. Ctrl-Alt-L should reformat code, but does nothing, same thing with Ctrl-Shift-F, for example. Meanwhile, combo with any number or +/-/= sign or arrows works well.
So what can be wrong? When I go to Setting->Keymaps and try the button "Find Actions by shortcut", press a combo there, it finds non-letter maps very well, but as I press combo with any button, it outputs, for example, "Ctrl+Alt+ unknown keycode 0x0"
Got a terrible headache with this... Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have non-US layout as a default one. Java doesn't like it and generates events with invalid keycodes. I'm not sure we can develop an easy workaround for the issue. As a countermeasure you can assign US a primary layout.

Comment: thanks much, but the best workaround I found out was switching to Gentoo+LXDE where keyboard shortcuts in AS work perfectly and don't interfere with desktop environment shortcuts in any way :) keyboard layout doesn't matter, whether there is RU layout enabled or not.